# enterprise app distribution using OTA give error message in safari?

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise, ota

We distributed our enterprise app using OTA. When we open "App download URL" first time in iPhone browser it show "would you like to install app" alert.

[image]

if User is tap on cancel button and re-open the "App download URL" again in same tab.it shows "Open this page in "App Store"?" alert, and when user tap on open button it display "would you like to install app".

[image]

Can some one help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a landing page with a link to your plist file:

> itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=YOUR_LINK_TO_PLIST

Comment: My app properly download from URL, but it show extra alert when i tap cancel button on first alert and try again to download app.